# Laravel PHP 4: modifying controller results in 'Creating default object from empty value' issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to modify a controller from a third-party package by having it be used locally instead of from the package source.  When it is used from the package source, everything runs fine but when I use it locally, I keep getting a 'Creating default object from empty value' error.

**Controller:**

```
use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\AlbumsController; /* Third party controller */

use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\PhotosController; /* Third party controller */

use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Validators as Validators; /* Third party validator */

class GalleryController extends BaseController {


/* The album model @var \JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Album */
protected $album;

/*The photo model @var \JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Photo */

protected $photo;

/* Instantiate the controller 
 * @param \JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Album $album
 * @param \JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Models\Photo $photo
 * @return void
*/

public function __construct()
{
    $this->album = \App::make('Repositories\AlbumRepository');
    $this->photo = \App::make('Repositories\PhotoRepository');
}

/*Listing all albums * @return \Illuminate\View\View */

  public function index()
  {
    $allAlbums = $this->album->all();
    /* Error occurs at line of code below */
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('gallery::index', array('allAlbums' => $allAlbums));
  }
}
```

Since I am referencing the third-party controllers above with the 'use' statements at the beginning of the controller, I don't understand why I keep getting this error.

Comment: Does it say where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: Yes, if you look at my line of code above, it tells me the error occurs at the second line of code within my 'public function index()' method where the line '$this-layout->content...' begins.

Comment: Ouh sorry, missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps. But my suspicion lies on two questions:

1. whether gallery::index exists or lies in the correct path
2. you may dd($allAlbums ) to let us know more possible info.

Comment: I actually switched back to using the 'package' version of the controller since what I'm trying to accomplish doesn't require me to modify the controller.  I think what was happening was the controllers weren't being accessed correctly and thus returning 'null' or empty results.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: After more experimenting, I figured out that the 'layout' file from my other blade file wasn't being called and therefore 'layout' in the line '$this->layout->content = \View::make('gallery::index', array('allAlbums' => $allAlbums)); ' was coming up as a 'null' or empty reference.